# Automatic connection of a new table in a existing Mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I have a schema on my db where there are some tables. I have to create a table into this schema and i have to connect it with the others already present on the schema.I make an example:

Tables already present:

```
SCHOOL(IdSchool,NumStud,IdCountry);
SHOP(IdShop,IdCountry);
```

New table:

```
Country(IdCountry,....);
```

I want to know if there is an automatic mode to connect them (it means not to set the foreign key manually).

Comment: Database management systems don't try to guess and create relations between a newly created table and existing ones. They rather rely on `CREATE` or `ALTER` statements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to know if there is an automatic mode to connect them (it means not to set the foreign key manually).

No.

How is the DBMS to know that `Country.IdCountry` and `SCHOOL.IdCountry` are given the same name with the intention to be connected, instead of just accidentally?

You'll have to use `ALTER TABLE ... ADD FOREIGN KEY (...) REFERENCES ...`<sup>1</sup> to explicitly create the foreign key in the existing table.

---

*<sup>1</sup> Or `ALTER TABLE ... ADD CONSTRAINT ... FOREIGN KEY (...) REFERENCES ...`.*